# jasmine jquery test to check if correct arguments have been passed to a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am new to javascript testing.
I am using jasmine and need to test if correct arguments have been passed to a method.

This is my method:

```
    function myView(){
      if($('.view').is('.list')){
          myWindow('list');
      }else{
          myWindow('random');
      }
      $('.view').toggleClass('my-list');
    }

    function myWindow(list) {
      var url = /test.json;
      $.post(url, {"list": list});
    }

Here are my tests:

  describe('#myView', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      fixture.load('myview.html');
    });

    it('sets window to list', function(){
      expect(window.myWindow).toHaveBeenCalledWith('list');
    });
  });
```

I get the following error.

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.
```

If i add this line before the expect(which seems wrong because I am specifying the correct param which should be identified by test)

```
spyOn(window, myWindow('list'));
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined() method does not exist
```

Can someone show my a good way to write the above tests?

Comment: This could be causing an issue: myWinodw('list');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spyOn`'s second parameter is the name of the property you need to spy on. When you call `spyOn(window, myWindow('list'));`, your second parameter is the ***return value*** of `myWindow('list')` which is `undefined` => throws error: `undefined() method does not exist`

In your code, simply doing this should work:

```
describe('#myView', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      fixture.load('myview.html');
    });

    it('sets window to list', function(){
      spyOn(window, "myWindow");//spy the function
      myView();//call your method that in turn should call your spy
      expect(window.myWindow).toHaveBeenCalledWith('list');//verify
    });
  });
```

In software unit testing, there are concepts called [stub and mock objects](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html). These are dependencies of the method under test. `spyOn` is to create your fake objects to test your methods.

You're accessing the global `window` object ***directly***, that's really a problem in unit testing. **Although** Javascript is a ***dynamically typed*** language, we're still able to mock your `window` object (this is not possible with some ***statically-typed*** languages like c#). **But** to create a good unit-testable code, I recommend you should redesign your code to inject it from outside.

```
function myView(awindow){ //any dependency should be injected, this is an example to inject it via parameter

      if($('.view').is('.list')){
          awindow.myWindow('list');
      }else{
          awindow.myWindow('random');
      }
      $('.view').toggleClass('my-list');
    }
```

Try this:

```
describe('#myView', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      fixture.load('myview.html');
    });

    it('sets window to list', function(){
      var spy = {myWindow:function(list){}};
      spyOn(spy, "myWindow"); //create a spy
      myView(spy); //call your method that in turn should call your spy
      expect(spy.myWindow).toHaveBeenCalledWith('list'); //verify
    });
  });
```

One more thing, jQuery code like this is not quite a good candidate for unit testing as ***it involves DOM manipulation in your code***. If you have time, you should take a look at [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) framework that separates your View (DOM) from your model (logic), uses [dependency injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to make your code testable.